# Thymeleaf th:text="#{date.format}" working but has no entry in messages.properties

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my messages properties I have defined many texts and they all work... but I don't know why.

Here is the template div I'm concerned with:

```
<div>
                <label for="datePlanted">
                    <span th:text="#{seedstarter.datePlanted}">Date planted</span>
                    (<span th:text="#{date.format}">YYYY/MM/DD</span>)
                </label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{datePlanted}" th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
            </div>
```

But there's no date.format entry in my message properties! What's going on here?

My only clue is in my WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class SpringWebConfig
        extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
.
.
.
@Override
    public void addFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {
        super.addFormatters(registry);
        registry.addFormatter(varietyFormatter());
        registry.addFormatter(dateFormatter());
    }

    @Bean
    public VarietyFormatter varietyFormatter() {
        return new VarietyFormatter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DateFormatter dateFormatter() {
        return new DateFormatter();
    }
```

Messages.properties

```
title.application=Spring Thyme Seed-Starter Manager
title.list=Seed Starter List
title.new=Add new Seed Starter

date.format=MM/dd/yyyy
bool.true=yes
bool.false=no

seedstarter.data=Seed Starter data
seedstarter.create=Add Seed Starter
seedstarter.row.add=Add row
seedstarter.row.remove=Remove row

seedstarter.datePlanted=Date planted
seedstarter.covered=Covered
seedstarter.type=Type
seedstarter.features=Features
seedstarter.rows=Rows

seedstarter.type.WOOD=Wood
seedstarter.type.PLASTIC=Plastic

seedstarter.feature.SEEDSTARTER_SPECIFIC_SUBSTRATE=Seed starter-specific substrate
seedstarter.feature.FERTILIZER=Fertilizer used
seedstarter.feature.PH_CORRECTOR=PH Corrector used

seedstarter.rows.head.rownum=Row
seedstarter.rows.head.variety=Variety
seedstarter.rows.head.seedsPerCell=Seeds per cell

typeMismatch.datePlanted=Date has an incorrect format (see pattern)
typeMismatch.seedsPerCell=Seeds per cell must be an integer number
```

Comment: formatting what ? `th:text="#{date.format(???)}">` . Assuming it is `datePlanted`, check `getter` method for this.

Comment: @want2learn See that's my problem... XD. It's missing what I thought is critical parameters... but this is how the Thymeleaf tutorial works...

Comment: @want2learn The Getters are /s , /s param save, /s param addRow, /s  removeRow

Comment: You must be getting something like `??date.format_en_US??`.

Comment: @want2learn II found somethjing

Answer (score 0):

**DateFormatter.java**
 This file was also in the project. It contains

> final String format = this.messageSource.getMessage("date.format",
>   null, locale);

I don't know much about MessageSource except its a Spring library and it has 3 methods that return a string and takes "String code", a default message, locale or MessageSourceResolvable.
I'm pretty stumped about how this is working down to the details but I see DateFormatter handles the view like that...

**DateFormatter.java**

```
 public class DateFormatter implements Formatter<Date> {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;


    public DateFormatter() {
        super();
    }

    public Date parse(final String text, final Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = createDateFormat(locale);
        return dateFormat.parse(text);
    }

    public String print(final Date object, final Locale locale) {
        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = createDateFormat(locale);
        return dateFormat.format(object);
    }

    private SimpleDateFormat createDateFormat(final Locale locale) {
        final String format = this.messageSource.getMessage("date.format", null, locale);
        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        return dateFormat;
    }

}
```